# google maps api add button to pan back to user location using geolocationmarker-compiled.js

Tags: html, google-maps, geolocation

Here is my code...  and i'm using   ../geolocationmarker-compiled.js to find the user location.

http://deepfrogphoto.com/Brett-Pelletier-Photography/Links/maps/wasatch-ski-map-mobile.htm

I would love to add a button that pans (centers) back to the user location if they scroll around on the map and want to go back to their location (the nice blue dot)  Can anyone help me out? I have no idea what I'm doing, but got all this to work somehow so far.   I would be forever grateful to add a button that will pan back to the user location.  Thanks for any help ahead of time...

```
var map, GeoMarker;      

function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 20,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.563855, -111.675426),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);

  GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
  GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
    alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
  });

  GeoMarker.setMap(map);

  trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map); 

  layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
      select: "skilines",
      from: "1R5pCEyNN74N8Dt9MkfNXA6A9D1HbQESzOR1fYFa7",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });   

  layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
      select: "resorts",
      from: "19iu58FDFcBIZZ-wU1iZcf89AI5ABDJ7YTv355su5",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });      

  layer3 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: { enabled: false },
    query: {
      select: "summerhiking",
      from: "1t1XNnG7J7Zu1p5mIUpm6qIGVYwzhkCgPy_je0IKr",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });       
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

if(!navigator.geolocation) {
  alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can recenter the map on the GeoMarker like this:

```
map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition());
```

working code snippet:

```js
var map, GeoMarker;

function toggleLayer(this_layer) {
  if (this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

function originalCenter() {
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(40.563855, -111.675426));
}

function recenterMapOnGeoLoc() {
  map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition());
}

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.563855, -111.675426),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
  GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({
    fillColor: '#808080'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
    alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
  });

  GeoMarker.setMap(map);

  trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);

  layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "skilines",
      from: "1R5pCEyNN74N8Dt9MkfNXA6A9D1HbQESzOR1fYFa7",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "resorts",
      from: "19iu58FDFcBIZZ-wU1iZcf89AI5ABDJ7YTv355su5",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  layer3 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "summerhiking",
      from: "1t1XNnG7J7Zu1p5mIUpm6qIGVYwzhkCgPy_je0IKr",
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

if (!navigator.geolocation) {
  alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@master/archive/geolocationmarker/src/geolocationmarker.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="recenter" onclick="recenterMapOnGeoLoc();" value="recenter" />
<input type="button" id="original" onclick="originalCenter();" value="original center" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9t75usaz/2/)